# Do I need to manually close a .NET SqlConnection, if it throws an exception inside a `using` statement?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, using, sqlconnection

If a `SqlConnection` throws an exception during execution inside a `using` statement, do I need to manually close the connection in a `finally` ? or will the scope of the `using` statement call the `Dispose` method (on the `SqlConnection`) for me ... which therefore executes the `.Close();` method for me (automatically)?

for example:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
{
   sqlConnection.Open();

   throw new Exception("boom!");
}
```

vs

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        throw new Exception("boom!");
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConection.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, does wrapping this in a `TransactionScope` + an exception is throw, affect how I should `.Close()` or the `using` scope auto-does this for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is still disposed if it is within the `using`

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called **even if an
>   exception occurs** while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.
>
> Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).